# ¿Cómo mostrar solo 1 decimal en gráfico con plot_ly?

Tags: r, plotly

Quería pedir su ayuda, tengo un gráfico realizado en plot_ly, y me gustaría mostrar solo 1 decimal para cada valor. Actualmente se muestran distinta cantidad de decimales dependiendo del valor.

Tengo la siguiente tabla

| tipo | cantidad |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3093 |
| b | 915 |
| c | 20787 |

El código es:

```
fig <- aux %>% plot_ly(labels = ~tipo, values = ~count, marker = list(colors = c("#51B7DF","#87C6DD","#B4D4DE"),line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)))
      fig <- fig %>% add_pie(hole = 0.5)
      fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "<b>Tipo de agentes artísticos, culturales y patrimoniales</b>",  showlegend = TRUE,
                            xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                            yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
      fig
```

Intenté con round, pero no tuve lo esperado, los porcentajes siguen siendo:

```
a= 12.5%
b= 3.69%
c= 83.8%
```

Comment: Hola Lucas Tapia Gómez! Bienvenido! Será más fácil que recibas ayuda si tu pregunta puede ser reproducida por miembros de la comunidad. Para eso es importante que incluyas los datos de manera que puedan ser copiados directamente  (usa en R el siguiente código sobre los datos `dput(datos)`) y no como imágenes. Sería valioso que incluyas el código que genera el gráfico antes de pasarlo a plotly.

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar el formato decimal del porcentaje, puedes usar el párametro ´texttemplate´ pero también tienes que tener en cuenta que lo que se hace es un recorte de decimales por lo que finalmente podrías terminar con áreas que no sumen exactamente el 100%:

```
aux %>% 
  plot_ly(labels = ~tipo, 
          values = ~count,    
          marker = list(colors = c("#51B7DF","#87C6DD","#B4D4DE"),
                                     line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
          texttemplate="%{percent:.1%f}"
          ) %>% 
  add_pie(hole = 0.5) %>% 
  layout(title = "<b>Tipo de agentes artísticos, culturales y patrimoniales</b>",  
         showlegend = TRUE,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)
         )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]